# Difference between Lineage os and Cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, lineageos

I want to know if there in big difference in Lineage OS and CyanogenMod ROM's ?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165453/cyanogenmod-to-lineage-os-how-does-it-affect-current-users

Answer (score 4):

At the birth of Lineage OS, it's a direct fork (i.e. full copy) of CyanogenMod sources at that time, so it's obvious that LOS is a *continuation* of CM, not a *replacement* to it. Thus, aside from differences introduced by individual maintainers, and a few renames here and there in the OS, all that's left is the ROM's age - a CM ROM is definitely compiled before the incident, while a Lineage one is after.

What this means for you is just like what a newer CM version compared to an older one - most likely, the newer the better.

Comment: To put it into numbers: CM ends with 13.* while LOS starts with 14.*. Apart from that (and what one expects from newer versions of the same tree – as that's what the term [lineage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineage_(genetic)) refers to), one key element is that root access no longer ships "out of the box", but must be added (flashed) manually in addition to the ROM itself.

Comment: @Izzy There were official builds of CM14.1, and LineageOS for older devices ([example](https://download.lineageos.org/ghost)) or unofficial builds can extend back to 13 as well - in fact I was building and using them until last month. As for the `su` stuff... I always build with `WITH_SU=true`, but what you said is correct.

Comment: Oh – I wasn't aware of the exceptions, thanks for the notice! And sure, if you build yourself it's a different thing (root) – my comment was toward "official builds" :)

Answer (score 0):

There will be differences between the two. The only major one I'm currently aware of is that LOS will not be allow root access by default whereas CM does.

Comment: Good point, but there will be a separate add-on that restores built-in root; home-builders like me can also enable it when building easily.

Answer (score -3):

- Los os mean Lineage OS it came after cyanogenmod both LOS and CM have root access depend on your choices but in some official/unofficial Los rom need to download su zip file to flash in recovery(if there's only ADB gain root access)
- CM got many tweaks setting but Los add some security to make your device safe*it got many features I am sure that Los got better security than CM.

Advantages of security Los better but if performance CM better.

Comment: -1 just for the last sentence: concrete proof?

Comment: @AndyYan I didn't think it was a secret that newer versions [had more dropped frames](https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Android-Performance-over-time-2-980x649.jpg).  That in my opinion implies a slow down or bottle necking of code.  I didn't upvote or downvote because it is written poorly but thought this was known.

Comment: @William Don't take the picture out of its context. The chart within the original article discusses the performance and battery deterioration within the use cycle of *the same phone hardware/OS* - there's even explicit mention of the reason, "presumably from the user installing more apps", hence the introduction of more effective mechanism of background app management in Android O. The evolution of LOS itself is not a part of the problem. I gotta say there are some aspects of the evolution that I dislike, but they interfere with performance much less than the greedy 3rd-party apps.